# EF 4 Filter sub collection

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Im trying get all my maingroups with its related entities. And i would also like to filter the BuildingPartData collection without affecting any of the other entities. I have pretty much tried every thing i can think of but with no luck.

```
 test.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var buildingPartMainGroups = (from buildingPartMainGroup in test.BuildingPartMainGroup
                                      from buildingPartSubGroup in buildingPartMainGroup.BuildingPartSubGroup
                                      from buildingPart in buildingPartSubGroup.BuildingPart
                                      from buildingPartData in buildingPart.BuildingPartData
                                      where buildingPartData.StatusPendingApprove == true
                                      //let buildingPartData = buildingPartMainGroup.BuildingPartSubGroup.Where(x => x.BuildingPart.Any(o => o.BuildingPartData.Any(y => y.StatusPendingApprove == true)))
                             select new
                             {
                                 BuildingPartMainGroups = buildingPartMainGroup,
                                 BuildingPartDatas = buildingPartData

                             }).ToList().Select(c => c.BuildingPartMainGroups);

        foreach (var bb in buildingPartMainGroups)
        {
            foreach(var tt in bb.BuildingPartSubGroup)
            {
                foreach (var oo in tt.BuildingPart)
                {
                    foreach (var ww in oo.BuildingPartData)
                    {
                        bool tes4t = ww.StatusPendingApprove;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the model

http://mimo-design.com/model.png

Cant insert images yet..

```
var buildingPartMainGroups = test.BuildingPartMainGroup.Include("BuildingPartSubGroup.BuildingPart.BuildingPartData").
                                        Where(bpmg => bpmg.BuildingPartSubGroup.
                                            Any(o => o.BuildingPart.
                                                Any(x => x.BuildingPartData.
                                                    Any(u => u.StatusPendingApprove == true))));
```

It only filtered my BuildingPartMainGroup entity. I would like to have all my BuildingPartMainGroup entities, with a condition / filter on BuildingPartData

Comment: A little more documentation about the object model / entity model could be nice.

Comment: That clarifies a lot. See my second answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already think of something like:

```
context.BuildingPartMainGroup
 .Inlcude("BuildingPartSubGroups.BuildingParts.BuildingPartData")
 .Where<BuildingPartMainGroup>(bpmg => bpmg.BuildingPartSubGroups.Any<BuildingPartSubGroup>(etc...
```

Comment: Do you have the navigation properties in place for: .Inlcude("BuildingPartSubGroups.BuildingParts.BuildingPartData")? Else it won't work. Check your entity model. Do you have a normalized database with foreign keys etc.? I advice you to do so to get the maximum out of EF.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Any. Any evaluates to a boolean. So what you actually are doing is collecting BuildingPartMainGroup that have at a minimum 1 BuildingPartSubGroup that has a minimum of 1...that has a minimum of one BuildingPartData which has StatusPendingApprove == true.

Try considering chaining the Where<>() extension method all the way down the object graph.

Hope this helps...

EDIT:

```
context.BuildingPartMainGroups
    .Inlcude("BuildingPartSubGroups.BuildingParts.BuildingPartData")
    .Where<BuildingPartMainGroup>
    (bpmg => bpmg.BuildingPartSubGroups.Where<BuildingPartSubGroup>
    (bpsg => bpsg.BuildingParts.Where<BuildingPart>
    (bp => bp.BuildingPartData"s".Where<BuildingPartData>
    (bpd => bpd.StatusPendingApprove == true))))
```

I wonder if you need the include right here. If you're solely interested in the BuidlingPartMainGroups without the associated data it's not necessary.

A helpful tip could be to use an SQl Profiler to see the exact SQL query that EF generates. this way you gain some more understanding in what your LinqToEntities query generates for SQL.

Comment: I see, can you give an example? Cant figure out how to chain where extension :-/

Comment: Thank you for helping my out here. Nice tip with the SQL Profiler i have a look at that. The last statement in the example you gave returns a IEnumerable<T> but where except an boolean

Comment: Is it solved now? Or need some more help? A good tip would be to read Julie Lerman's Programming Entity Framework!

Comment: The nested where example you gave will not work. The last where in the chain returns a IEnumerable and not a boolean. So if you can help me with that one i can see if your idea is going to work :-)